# Tensoring of the identity morphism of the monoidal unit

Tags: monoidal-categories

This is a rather elementary question about strict monoidal categories.

Let $C$ be a monoidal category, $I \xrightarrow{id_I} I$ be the identity morphism of the unit object. How do I show that for any other morphism $f$, $f \otimes id_I = f = id_I \otimes f$?